# How can I dynamically add a widget that I can then fetch with a Gtk.Builder instance?

Tags: pygi

If I want to dynamically add a row to a vbox and populate it...  I need a way to see if that row already exists.  So the thought train is "Try to fetch the box with builder instance.  If it fails, add a row and add the box"  If I add the box dynamically, what flags do I have to set or what calls do I have to make in order to be able to fetch it with builder?